# 3D plot on latex is incorrect

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:5,y domain=-5:5, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$}]
            \addplot3[surf]{x*tan(pi/3)+y^2*(2*x*tan(pi/3)+x*tan(pi/4-pi/6)-x*tan(pi/3))/((x/cos((pi/4)-pi/6))^2)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried plotting the same equation on geogebra3D, which uses the same notation. I should be getting a cone, but I don't.

Comment: you shouldn't show only snippets, they are difficult to test. Always show a small but complete and compilable document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer done

Comment: The trig functions in `pgf` assume degrees as input, but that wouldn't affect the general shape I think. This doesn't look like a cone: `https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x*tan%28pi%2F3%29%2By%5E2*%282*x*tan%28pi%2F3%29%2Bx*tan%28pi%2F4-pi%2F6%29-x*tan%28pi%2F3%29%29%2F%28%28x%2Fcos%28%28pi%2F4%29-pi%2F6%29%29%5E2%29` (link didn't work, copy-paste URL)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. https://www.geogebra.org/3d/cbnkk8fg

Comment: Yeah, I saw that Geogebra did something quite different. No idea why though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of discarding coordinates where you divide by zero, you can jump over them `unbounded coords=jump`. Also I guess that you want `trig format plots=rad`

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump, trig format plots=rad, domain=0:5,y domain=-5:5, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$}]
            \addplot3[surf]{x*tan(pi/3)+y^2*(2*x*tan(pi/3)+x*tan(pi/4-pi/6)-x*tan(pi/3))/((x/cos((pi/4)-pi/6))^2)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Surface graph]

Edit:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-4, xmax=4,
ymin=-4, ymax=4,
zmin=-2, zmax=5,
unbounded coords=jump,
trig format plots=rad,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
domain=-2:4,y domain=-2:2,
]
 \addplot3[surf]{x*tan(pi/3)+y^2*(2*x*tan(pi/3)+x*tan(pi/4-pi/6)-x*tan(pi/3))/((x/cos((pi/4)-pi/6))^2)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Surface Graph - cones]

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/3d/cbnkk8fg but the graph still isn't accurate

Comment: I can not say what is wrong in Geogebra. -see wolframalpha from @Torbjørn T.

Comment: The formula is defined by the cone. While I can't say 100% that my derivation of it is correct, it seems extremely unlikely that I accidentally got the result I wanted on geogebra

Comment: It all dependents on which scale you see the plot - do not dismiss wolframalpha AND PGFPlots as incorrect. I have made some changes to reproduce the scale from Geogebra. -there is still the issue with the jump where there is division by zero. -see edit.

Comment: I know of the division by 0 error. Thanks for the help. I was initially under the impression that PGF and wolfram used the same code. Do you know how I can get a better render for values closer to 0. And as an aside, do you know how to rotate the z?

Comment: Instead of plotting across `x=0`, you could make two  `\addplot3` with domains from e.g `domain=0.1:4` and `domain=-4:-0.1`. -Or a bit more advanced, you could use `x filter/.expression=...`. To rotate the view angle, you can add `view={100}{100}` to the axis and experiment with the values. Edit: I now think that it is not possible with a filter - the best way is to split the plot in two.